# CountDownLatch to hold the parent thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, countdownlatch

How can I hold the main thread until all 5 tasks(threads) have been completed?

```
class ReadMessages {

    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

void readMessage(List<Messages> msg ) 
{
   CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(msg.size); /// lets say msg.size()=5

           for( Messages m : msg) {
                executorService.submit(() -> dbservice.processInDB(message)); //execute saveInDb paaralllely in 5 different threads 
            }

           //Hold the main thread until all 5 threads have completed their work. i.e make latch count to 0 
           
           //then send email
           emailService();
        }
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [CountDownLatch#await](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await()). Your submitted tasks will need to actually count down the latch though.

Comment: @MarcBaumbach I tried using it but its not executing properly.Can you modify my code or where should i put it

Comment: @MarcBaumbach Thanks i had placed `latch.countDown();` outside the submit .Thast why it was not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [await](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await()) method of the `CountDownLatch` to hold up the thread until the latch reaches zero. You'll want to also modify your submitted task to count down the latch as well. Something like this:

```
void readMessage(List<Messages> msg) {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(msg.size); /// lets say msg.size()=5

    for(Messages m : msg) {
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            try {
                dbservice.processInDB(m); //execute saveInDb paaralllely in 5 different threads 
            } finally {
                // One of the messages has been processed, count down the latch by 1
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
    }

    //Hold the main thread until all 5 threads have completed their work. i.e make latch count to 0 
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    
    //then send email
    emailService();
}
```

Comment: One thing to note, is that you'll want to be very careful that the line `dbservice.processInDb(m);` never throws. If it does, you'll certainly want to catch all possible exceptions and countdown the latch or somehow propagate that up. Otherwise you'll get stuck with a hanging thread if any of the messages fails.

Comment: .Ok .`dbservice.processInDb(m);` is  not throwing any exception .Logic is written in TRY-CATCH.Plus i am using  `latch.await();` with `TimeOut` to avoid hanging threads. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @PaleBlueDot To be more clear, the call to `countDown()` should be done in a `finally` block to ensure it's invoked whether `processInDb` succeeds or fails. For example: `try { dbservice.processInDb(m); } finally { latch.countDown(); }`.

Comment: @PaleBlueDot Note another option, other than `CountDownLatch`, is to make use of [`ExecutorService#invokeAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)) (or its timeout overload).

Comment: I've put the `countDown()` call into a `finally`... it's really the least we can add to make sure people aren't getting stuck threads. Thanks for the call out @Slaw!